# Show portfolio items in template - how?

Tags: wp-query

I have made my archive-portfolio.php-file as desired and it works as it is supposed to. However, I don't want to use that file. I want to create a template, name it for instance cars-template.php and then include it under "Cars".

I assume that I need to make a query. However, it hasn't worked out for me yet. I have created my porfolio using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/portfolio-post-type/. I am using the Genesis Framework if that helps.

How can I get further with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is cars? A custom taxonomy? If so, what is the identifier of that taxonomy?

Comment: @cybmeta Cars is just a page, where I wish to include the portfolio items.

Comment: You can build a [page template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) a make a [secondary loop in the template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage). Please, break down where do you have the problem exactly. Anyway, if you are going to use that page template for listing portfolio items, I don't see the adventage of doing that extra job and not customizing the `archive-portfolio.php` template directly.